# Can I listen for all drag & drop events in java?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

I would like to listen for all the drag and drop events on Swing.

One way I managed to listen for drag events was by adding:

```
final long mask = AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK + AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK;

AWTEventListener eventListener = new AWTEventListener() {
    public void eventDispatched(final AWTEvent event) {}
};
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(eventListener, mask);
```

but this does not get drop events, not even release events from the mouse when dropping.
Is there a way to intercept all drag and drop events in the application, not on each component separately?

Comment: I want to record everything the user does, extract scenarios and then create automated tests on those scenarios.

Comment: ambitious :-) The global listener is very low-level, so you'll get the raw mouse/motion events, but most probably not any higher level ones like dragEvent/dropEvent. Never tried, though. Btw, mouseMotion != mouse, to get the release/pressed along with moved/dragged you'll have to add the latter mask as well

Comment: I missed adding that in the question because I wanted it to be as short and concise as possible. I modified the mask in the question as I'm currently using it but even so the release event isn't caught so I thought it's consumed by the drop event.

Comment: yeah, just checked: all the dropXXEvents are not even AWTEvents, so not accessible by a AWTEventListner. And the system swallows all mouse events while in a drag operation. Interesting question!

Comment: The fact that d&d events do not extend AWTEvent made me doubt the possibility of intercepting them from the beginning. I hoped that there is some sort of global listener that I missed in java.awt.dnd or java.awt.dnd.peer packages. 
Anyway, I think a way to do what I want would be to install all drag support through a util class which receives a delegate wrapped in a logging decorator but I think that's overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete (maybe not even a feasable ;-) solution to your requirement, but might get you started.

As noted, all low-level input events (like mouseEvents, depending on the underlying OS there might be others as well) are swallowed by the dnd-subsystem during a drag. Internally, they are transformed into DragXXEvents which in turn are fired by the DragSource. The dragSource is a singleton that's re-used across all dnd operations. So a way to go might be:

- grab the global DragSource
- register a DragSource/Motion/Listener
- monitor the information from the DragSourceEvent as needed

Some snippet:

```
DragSource source = DragSource.getDefaultDragSource();
DragSourceMotionListener dsml = new DragSourceMotionListener() {

    @Override
    public void dragMouseMoved(DragSourceDragEvent dsde) {
        debug(dsde);
    }
};
source.addDragSourceMotionListener(dsml);

// just some logging
protected void debug(DragSourceEvent dsde) {
    DragSourceContext context = dsde.getDragSourceContext();
    Component source = context.getComponent();
    String text = source != null ? source.getName() : "none";
    LOG.info(text + " x/y " + dsde.getX() + "/" + dsde.getY());
}
```

Still a lot a work ahead ...